# Type inference fails when defining lexer using makeTokenParser

Tags: haskell, parsec

I have the following code:

```
module Lexer (lexer) where                                                                                                                                                                                                
import Text.Parsec                                                                                                                                                                                                        
import Text.Parsec.Token                                                                                                                                                                                                  
import Text.Parsec.Language                                                                                                                                                                                               

opChars = "<>+=*-/!:"                                                                                                                                                                                                     

def = emptyDef {                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    commentStart = "/*"                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  , commentEnd = "*/"                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  , identStart = letter                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  , identLetter = alphaNum                                                                                                                                                                                                
  , opStart = oneOf opChars                                                                                                                                                                                               
  , opLetter = oneOf opChars                                                                                                                                                                                              
  , reservedOpNames = ["+", "-", "*", "!=", "==", ":=", "<", "<=", ">", ">="]                                                                                                                                             
  , reservedNames = ["and", "not", "or", "p_", "when", "output", "of"]                                                                                                                                                    
  }

lexer = makeTokenParser def
```

However, when I try to import this file in `ghci`, I get the following error:

```
Prelude> :l Lexer.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Lexer            ( Lexer.hs, interpreted )

Lexer.hs:11:18:
    No instance for (Stream s0 m0 Char) arising from a use of `letter'
    The type variables `s0', `m0' are ambiguous
    Relevant bindings include
      def :: GenLanguageDef s0 u m0 (bound at Lexer.hs:8:1)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Monad m =>
               Stream Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString m Char
        -- Defined in `Text.Parsec.Prim'
      instance Monad m =>
               Stream Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString m Char
        -- Defined in `Text.Parsec.Prim'
      instance Monad m => Stream Data.Text.Internal.Lazy.Text m Char
        -- Defined in `Text.Parsec.Prim'
      ...plus two others
    In the `identStart' field of a record
    In the expression:
      emptyDef
        {commentStart = "/*", commentEnd = "*/", identStart = letter,
         identLetter = alphaNum, opStart = oneOf opChars,
         opLetter = oneOf opChars, reservedOpNames = ["+", "-", "*", ....],
         reservedNames = ["and", "not", "or", ....]}
    In an equation for `def':
        def
          = emptyDef
              {commentStart = "/*", commentEnd = "*/", identStart = letter,
               identLetter = alphaNum, opStart = oneOf opChars,
               opLetter = oneOf opChars, reservedOpNames = ["+", "-", ....],
               reservedNames = ["and", "not", ....]}
```

Note that this only happened after splitting apart the file; I previously had some code that consumed "lexer" in the same module, and then separated it out.

What type annotations do I need to provide in order for this to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to annotate: `def :: LanguageDef st`. That will fix `s0` to `String` and `m0` to `Identity`.

Here's a... loose explanation.

Let's pick through the types from the outside in. (That's not necessarily how inference works, but we usually have or can get the types of top-level bindings.) The inferred type for `def` is noted in the error message: `GenLanguageDef s0 u m0`. Looking at the definition of [`GenLanguageDef`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.7/docs/Text-Parsec-Token.html#t:GenLanguageDef), the inferred type of `identStart` is therefore `ParsecT s0 u m0 Char`.

`letter` has type `Stream s m Char => ParsecT s u m Char`. Unifying that with the type of `identStart`, we get the constraint `Stream s0 m0 Char` that needs to be satisfied somehow.

The [monomorphism restriction](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction) prohibits the compiler from simply floating the inferred constraint out to the type of `def`. With the restriction disabled, `def` has the inferred type `Stream s0 m0 Char => GenLanguageDef s0 u m0`. The consumer may fix the type variables, as you did in your previous one-file solution.

Alternately, providing the concrete signature I suggested simply fixes the variables `s0` and `m0`. Now the compiler can satisfy the class constraint directly, since it knows `Identity` is a `Monad` and that there's an instance `Monad m => Stream String m Char`.

(You would think that, because `emptyDef` has type `LanguageDef st`, which translates to `GenLanguageDef String st Identity`, `def` would have that type. Ah, but you're using record update syntax, which allows the type variables to change.)

Answer (score 2):

Use the pragma:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
```

Comment: To elaborate: the monomorphism restriction is why it stopped working when you split it into two files. Before, it could infer a monomorphic type because you used `lexer` elsewhere in the file.